# Java Generics Unchecked Cast Warning: abstract class A<T extends A>

Tags: java, generics

Yet another Java Generics unchecked cast question coming up:

We have something like the following:

```
public abstract class A<T extends A> {

    public final T doSomething() {
        return (T)this; //unchecked cast A<T> to T
    }
}
```

So, is this unchecked cast something we can surpress or is there really a case where this can fail?

Comment: Shouldn't the class declaration be `A<T extends A<T>>?

Comment: my view on "self type" - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30382847  - there's also a "purist" solution for this kind of problem, `getThis` - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31323115

Comment: You might find  some more if you search for [(F-)Bounded quantification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantification).

Comment: @awksp yeah it probably should, but I don't think it is really needed and it would just confuse me some more.

Comment: @Tom Thanks a lot! Didn't really knew how to search for this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it absolutely can fail.  Example:

```
public class B extends A<B> {
    // empty
}

public class C extends A<B> {
    // empty
}

public class AnotherClass {
    public void someMethod() {
        A<B> c = new C();
        B b = c.doSomething();  /* ClassCastException */
    }
}
```

Note that @awksp's suggested change to ...

```
abstract class A<T extends A<T>> { /* ... */ }
```

... does not rescue this example.  With that change, the type safety diagnostic in `A.doSomething()` remains the only one, and of course `AnotherClass.someMethod()` still throws `ClassCastException`.

Answer (score 2):

> is there really a case where this can fail?

Sure.  Here's an example:

```
class A<T extends A<?>> {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    T get() {
        return (T) this;
    }
}
```

```
class B<T extends A<T>> extends A<T> {

}
```

```
class C<T extends B<T>> extends A<T> {

}
```

Now C's method will return a C, but C isn't a legal substitution for `T extends B<T>`, since C *doesn't* extend B.